# How to specify Input to AWS Lambda from SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have created a lambda function and I want to trigger it from Amazon SQS. For the Event value in handler (Event,Context), I want to specify a value from this SQS. I want to specify a big JSON. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Sample Events Published by Event Sources - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/eventsources.html), Amazon SQS will send this event information to the AWS Lambda function:

```
{
     "Records": [
        {
            "messageId": "c80e8021-a70a-42c7-a470-796e1186f753",
            "receiptHandle": "...",
            "body": "{\"foo\":\"bar\"}",
            "attributes": {
                "ApproximateReceiveCount": "3",
                "SentTimestamp": "1529104986221",
                "SenderId": "594035263019",
                "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp": "1529104986230"
            },
            "messageAttributes": {},
            "md5OfBody": "9bb58f26192e4ba00f01e2e7b136bbd8",
            "eventSource": "aws:sqs",
            "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-2:594035263019:NOTFIFOQUEUE",
            "awsRegion": "us-west-2"
        }
    ]
```

The body of the SQS message is provided in the `body` parameter.

The [maximum size of an SQS message](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-limits.html) is 256 KB, but I'm not sure you'd be able to pass something that big to Lambda. I recommend you try it and see!

Worst case, store the content in Amazon S3 and pass a reference to the S3 object in the message.

Comment: Yes exactly, the entire Record is sent as Event to lambda , how to make it send only the body to the Lambda

Comment: The Body is sent in the `Body` attribute. Your Lambda function can extract that field.

Answer (score 0):

Create an SQS queue.  This SQS queue should take s3 bucket names as an input.  Maybe it should also take the region of the s3 bucket as well? Might want to have it take a JSON object:

```
{"bucketname": "this_is_my_bucket", "region": "us-west-2"}
```